# Avoid partially initialized module ImportError

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

#### Context

Let's say I have the following module:

```
.
└── my_module
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── my_module_A.py (defines ClassA)
    └── my_module_B.py (defines ClassB, which needs ClassA)
```

and the files are the following:

```py
# __init__.py

from .my_module_A import ClassA
from .my_module_B import ClassB
```

```py
# my_module_A.py

from my_module import ClassB

class ClassA:

    def __init__(self, class_b: ClassB):
        pass
```

```py
# my_module_B.py

class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

The important thing is that `ClassB` requires an instance of `ClassA` to be
instantiated.

#### Problem

Importing the module `my_module` raises an `ImportError`:

```sh
>>> # Working directory is the parent of my_module
>>> import my_module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo/Module/my_module/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .my_module_A import ClassA
  File "foo/Module/my_module/my_module_A.py", line 3, in <module>
    from my_module import ClassB
ImportError: cannot import name 'ClassB' from partially initialized module 'my_module' (most likely due to a circular import) (foo/Module/my_module/__init__.py)
```

The problem seems to be the following. When importing `my_module`, Python goes
through its `__init__.py` and starts by importing `ClassA` from `my_module_A`.
This file imports itself `ClassB` from `my_module_B` so this class is imported
for `my_module` as well. After `my_module_A`, Python tries to import `ClassB`
from `my_module` ; but it was already imported by `my_module_A`, so Python
raises `ImportError`.

Python suggests that the error may come from a circular import, but this is not
the case here. I really think that the problem is that the class `ClassB` is
imported twice: if I do not import `my_module_B` in `__init__.py` and use a
relative import for `my_module_B` in `my_module_A`, the import is successful
and there is no exception raised.

#### Finding a solution

A possible solution is to use only relative imports in python files in
`my_module`. The problem is that some submodules in `my_module` required
themselves a lot of classes from `my_module` (about 20 for some of them) and it
is ugly and inconvenient for maintainers having to know precise file names
where classes are defined. So my question is: how can I keep using `from my_modyle import …` imports in `my_module` submodules? Thanks a lot.

P.S. Some of you may suggest to rethink my module organization. I thought of
that but there is no canonical way to do it and this flat structure is truly
easier and clearer. So if possible I would like to avoid this.

*Python version*: 3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is `ClassB` hasn't yet been loaded into `my_module` (in `__init__.py`) when `my_module_A` is being imported (this is hinted by the "partially initialized" bit in the error message).
You'll need to manually order the imports in `__init__.py` so that dependencies come before the modules that use them:

```python
# __init__.py

from .my_module_B import ClassB
from .my_module_A import ClassA  # uses ClassB
```

A more robust solution is to skip `__init__.py` and import directly from `my_module_B`, but as you say, this gets unwieldy with lots of modules.

```python
# my_module_A.py

# relative imports also work here
from my_module.my_module_B import ClassB

class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, class_b: ClassB):
        pass
```

Comment: This continues to suffer the same problem for me, class defined in classname.py, `from my_mod.classname import ClassName` leads to the error still. `from . import classname` and using `classname.ClassName` fails identically. I'm also not just using it for type hinting so I can't avoid it with `from future import __annotations__` or `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING` as I actually need the content...